# How can I use vue-router-tab in Vue3?

Tags: tabs, vue-router, vuejs3

I installed vue-router-tab. (npm i vue-router-tab -S) and configured.

main.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import RouterTab from "vue-router-tab";
import "vue-router-tab/dist/lib/vue-router-tab.css";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(RouterTab);
app.use(store);
app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");
```

router/index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import { RouterTabRoutes } from "vue-router-tab";
import Frame from "../components/layout/Frame.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: Frame,
    children: [
      ...RouterTabRoutes,
      {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        component: Home,
        meta: {
          title: "Home",
        },
      },
      {
        path: "/about",
        name: "About",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/About.vue"),
        meta: {
          title: "About",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

components/layout/Frame.vue

```
<template>
  <router-tab />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Frame",
  setup() {},
};
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
  </div>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>
```

npm run serve throws error.
[image]

It works fine in vue2, but in vue3, an error occurs saying the tabs property is not defined.

**How can I use vue-router-tab in Vue3? help me please.**

Comment: the [changelog](https://bhuh12.github.io/vue-router-tab/guide/changelog.html) says it only works with Vue 2.X. Maybe I am wrong. Could you build this tab component by yourself?

Comment: Thanks, but I need router-tab that works on vue3. Or I want to make it myself, but I don't know how to make it.